Error: Windows.old folder linked to the system
I am developing a tool with c# and robocopy to help me to backup and restore my data after re-install windows 10. For example selenium profiles from browsers, code repositories, etc. But i have problems maybe caused by the operating system like the followings.
I have noticed that the Windows.old folder created in the Windows 10 installation is linked to system folders. This causes several problems such as the following:

When using the Chrome browser, the respective folders on windows.old are also automatically updated.

If the name of a folder is changed on windows.old the change is also automatically reflected in the system folders and vice-versa.





When performing Windows.old backup to another location, on the destination the operating system created duplicate subfolders up to 11 levels of nesting that do not exist on the source on Windows.old, and the size of the folder increases too much as In the following example the subfolder DATOS DE PROGRAMA:


X:\Windows.old\Users\All Users\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Datos de programa\Mozilla-1de4eec8-1241-4177-a864-e594e8d1fb38

The described behavior is normal? How can Backup be done from the windows.old folder?
The windows.old content would not be linked online by the operating system to the original folders of the applications in the operating system to allow manipulating them, making backups and restoring data.

The contents of Windows.old will by default be automatically deleted 30 days after a feature version is installed. The simplest solution to this problem is to manually delete the folder earlier than that deadline. The only side effect is that you will be unable to rollback to the earlier version of Windows. Why are you backing up anything in that folder? I am unable to reproduce the reliance of this folder with any of my Chrome browsers on any machine in my Arsenal

The safe way to back up data is to make a complete disk image that would have all information, including that which is only a link in a folder. Simply backing up a folder such as Windows.old might save nothing of use, only links without a referent. One can mount that image and have access to any and all items in it.
